# Java - Why do only some error-throwing methods require error handling?

Tags: java, error-handling

For example, why is it that `ObjectOutputStream.close();`, which can throw an IOException, requires error handling (either a try-catch block or a throws declaration) while `Integer.parseInt(String s);`, which can throw a NumberFormatException, does not?

Comment: Read [unchecked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Comment: Because of a guy named Goodenough.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the language by design. `IOException` is a checked exception, and `NumberFormatException` is an unchecked exception (because it is a subtype of `RuntimeException`).